# mysql showing result sum in double

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

table1 = items
table2= sales

```
SELECT items.itemcode, items.itemname, 
       sum(items.totalnoofpcs)-ifnull(sum(sales.qty), 0)as sold 
FROM items 
   LEFT JOIN Sales ON items.itemcode = Sales.itemcode 
GROUP BY items.itemcode, items.itemname.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What do you want to achieve or what is the problem?

Comment: Sum for totalnoofpcs will be artificially inflated due to 1:m relationship. Sum sales qty in a derived table before join, or use analytic sum partition by item code to prevent inflated sum of totLnoofpcs.  What database and version?

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT i.itemcode, i.itemname,
       sum(i.totalnoofpcs)-coalesce(sum(s.qty), 0)as sold
FROM items i LEFT JOIN
     Sales s
     ON i.itemcode = s.itemcode
GROUP BY i.itemcode, i.itemname;
```

Presumably, there is one row per `itemcode` in the `items` table, so that is not affecting the results.  The logical conclusion is that `totalnoofpcs` is the cause -- it doesn't sound like the kind of variable that you would want added up per sale.

So, instead of `sum()`, use `max()` or include it in the `group by` keys:

```
SELECT i.itemcode, i.itemname,
       (i.totalnoofpcs - coalesce(sum(s.qty), 0)) as sold
FROM items i LEFT JOIN
     Sales s
     ON i.itemcode = s.itemcode
GROUP BY i.itemcode, i.itemname, i.totalnoofpcs;
```

Comment: SELECT i.itemcode, i.itemname,
       (i.totalnoofpcs - coalesce(sum(s.qty), 0)) as sold
FROM items i LEFT JOIN
     Sales s
     ON i.itemcode = s.itemcode
GROUP BY i.itemcode, i.itemname, i.totalnoofpcs;

Comment: same problem i.e sum in double in sold SELECT i.itemcode, i.itemname,
      same problem shwoing in sold in doulble pse SELECT i.itemcode, i.itemname,
       sum(i.totalnoofpcs) as pcs, coalesce(sum(s.qty), 0)as sold
FROM items i LEFT JOIN
     Sales s
     ON i.itemcode = s.itemcode
GROUP BY i.itemcode, i.itemname

please solve it

Comment: table 1 = items
table 2 = sales
table1 items:-
itemcode
itemname
totalnoofpcs
table2 sales:-
itemcode
itemname
qty
code="SELECT i.itemcode, i.itemname,
sum(i.totalnoofpcs) - (coalesce(sum(s.qty), 0)) as sold
FROM items i LEFT JOINSales s
ON i.itemcode = s.itemcode
GROUP BY i.itemcode, i.itemname" 
i was held stock 40 nos, sold 3 nos but balance shown 34 nos. this is my problem. pse solve it